# Files not appearing on SDcard despite being saved correctly; Appear in file explorer on device

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Edit: Below is my original question, written for OpenCV in Android. I was saving files correctly but the files were not showing up in My Computer on my laptop! Strange enough, they were showing up in Astro File Manager. See the answer for more details...

I have read/write permissions enabled. The 'cm' matrix is NOT null.

I am trying to check my images during my processing process to make sure they are being formed the right way.

Here is my C++ code in the android native environment:

```
 imwrite("/storage/emulated/0/stackovernose.jpg", cm);
```

cm is a MAT file. 
/storage/emulated/0 is hard-coded from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); The file is created, succesfully (the inner If tree is activated) but I can't find it on my phone? I've used similar code in the past and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. This time it's not working at all. What am I missing?

Comment: no idea about android, but usually you can't imwrite() as long as your fopen() is not closed ;)

Comment: Thank you, I think that is probably the problem. But I'm new to C++ and pointers confuse me... Can you tell me what the line is I need to add? I keep getting int / File* / Char C conversion errors

Comment: throw in a fclose(file); before the imwrite

Comment: Thank you for not belittling me... However this did not solve my problem. I think it might have to do with the imwrite function, I am not sure if fopen is even necessary, but thank you anyway

Comment: again, the left-open file handle was just a *second* problem added to the original one

Comment: just do the imwrite, forget the fopen and if statement

Comment: I have done this. The file is visible on my device (file chooser) but not in other situations. I think this is an android problem, not an OpenCV problem

Answer (score 2):

On some newer devices (Moto X, Nexus), you must disconnect, restart, and re-connect your device  in order for your files to refresh in My Computer. Optionally, you can download a file manager from the play store to see your files immediately after they are generated.

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63640/how-to-access-storage-emulated-0-from-pc. It says to reboot your phone